# Reading from JSON file, variable name is different, does not match

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to read from a JSON file, but it is formatted this way:

```
[
    {
        "INV#" : "123"
    },
    {
        "INV#" : "456"
    }
]
```

That variable name does not meet JavaScript or TypeScript naming. So I have the following object:

```js
export interface Invoice {
    invoiceNumber: number;
}

class myclass {
    private inv: Invoice[];
}
```

How can I read from that json file into this object. Making changes on the database variable is not an option. Changing the name of my interface variable is not possible in JavaScript. Somehow they have to match, but there must be a way to make the object property into mine.

Comment: Iterate over the objects and access `obj['INV#']`?

Comment: how can I do that? using keys just return the property name ("INV#") not the actual value...

Comment: If `obj['INV#']` results in `'INV#'` then the value is the same as the key (and is not a numeric string like "123") - which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// let's assume that you've read the json into some variable
let response = [
    {
        "INV#" : "123"
    },
    {
        "INV#" : "456"
    }
];

export interface Invoice {
    invoiceNumber: number;
}

class myclass {
    private inv: Invoice[];
    constructor(_response: any[]) {
        // do not forget to check _response for null/undefined, if it is an array or not, etc.
        this.inv = _response.map(obj => <Invoice>{
            invoiceNumber: parseInt(obj['INV#'])
        });
    }
}

// usage:
let some_var = new myclass(response);

// now some_var contains array of invoices internally.
```

Comment: worked just like magic!!! thank you very much, this solved my issue! you explained it like a boss. The object actually has more properties so I just kept adding them the same way I you did with invoiceNumber. Again, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please consider upvoting my answer too.